# How to view binary content of a C++ integer in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

```
int main()
{
     int a = 0;
}
```

I compile: `g++ -std=c++14 -g test.cpp`

Run program in gdb:

`gdb ./a.out`

`(gdb) break main`

`(gdb) run`

`(gdb) next`

What I have tried:

`(gdb) print /t &a`

That prints `11111111111111111111111111111111101110101111100`

That doesn't look like the right number, I was expecting 0000....0000. How can I print binary values from the memory location of the integer variable a ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use p /x to print something in hex.   Let us look after a has been set to 0.

```
(gdb) n
28               return(0);
(gdb) p a
$6 = 0
```

ok

```
(gdb) p /x a
$7 = 0x0
```

ok in hex

```
(gdb) p /x &a
$8 = 0x7fffffffe3dc
```

address of a in automatic memory (on the stack).

```
(gdb) p /t &a
$9 = 11111111111111111111111111111111110001111011100
```

looks like binary, and slightly different on my machine than yours. good.

> ```
> (gdb) print /t &a
> ```
>
> That prints 11111111111111111111111111111111101110101111100
>
> ```
> That doesn't look like the right number?
> ```

33 1's at the front, and the last 4 bits are 0xc.

Mine looks correct compared to hex.  0x7fffffffe3dc.

I suspect yours is too.

If you were expecting a bunch of 0's. that would be the value of a, not the address of a

```
(gdb) p /t a
$10 = 0
```

gdb shrunk the results - 0 is indeed a bunch of 0's.

Comment: my system is 64 bit

Comment: You can print literals in **gdb** as well:

Print an integer with 32nd bit set  
`p /t (1 << 31)`


Outputs:

`$1 = 10000000000000000000000000000000`

To print 64 bits literals, one can use:

`p /t (1UL << 63)`

Which outputs:

`$2 = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to print the address of *a* which is in the stack frame of main and has nothing to do with its value. Try:

`print /t a`

Answer (score 2):

You could also see it using a gui like: https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard which I recommend if you don't have a lot of experience with gdb. Also a simple cheat sheet will be helpful to have at hand: http://darkdust.net/files/GDB%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the links to resources, looks like they will be useful to me.

Comment: I hope so! those helped me a ton!